# How to model / where to store relational data between classes

Tags: architecture, design-patterns, databases, data

I'm trying to figure out the best design here, and I can see multiple approaches, but none that seems "right."

There are three relevant classes here: Base, TradingPost, and Resource. Each Base has a TradingPost which can offer various Resources depending on the Base's tech level.

Where is the right place to store the minimum tech level a base must possess to offer any given resource? A database seems like overkill. Putting it in each subclass of Resource seems wrong--that's not an intrinsic property of the Resource. Do I have a mediating class, and if so, how does it work? It's important that I not be duplicating code; that I have one place where I set the required tech level for a given item. Essentially, where does this data belong?

P.S. Feel free to change the title; I struggled to come up with one that fits.

Comment: It sounds like you can just keep this as an attribute of the base: a list of resources, and a correlating list of the minimal base level before that resource appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the responsibility of managing which `Resource`s are available in a `TradingPost` should be in a separate controller-like class, `TradingPostController` for example.

`TradingPostController` observes changes of `Base.techLevel` and updates the `TradingPost`'s set of offered `Resources` accordingly. In this approach, `TradingPostController` will contain a mapping of tech level -> resource set.

So the sequence of events would be:

- Tech-level of `Base` is increased.
- `Base` fires a "tech level changed" event.
- `TradingPostController` observes the event.
- `TradingPostController` updates `TradingPost.resources` (or so).

Good luck!